# Solving this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have no idea why I am having so many issues solving this matrix, but I am. I keep getting a negative answer for y, but they are all positive. The answer should be

x= 65, y= 30, and z= 45.

I had three equations that I put into matrix form and solved.

300x + 200y + 100z = 30000

200x + 100y + 200z = 25000

200y + 200z = 15000

I keep getting x=275, y=-150, and z=75
Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: It would be more helpful if you show your working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After dividing your equations by $100$ to make the numbers more manageable, we get
$$\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 2 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
300 \\
250 \\
150 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Subtracting $2/3$ of the first row from the second row, we get
$$\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & -1/3 & 4/3 \\
0 & 2 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
300 \\
50 \\
150 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Multiplying the second row by $3$, we get
$$\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 4 \\
0 & 2 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
300 \\
150 \\
150 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Adding $2$ times the second row to the third row gives us
$$\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 10 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
300 \\
150 \\
450 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The third row is now $10z = 450$, so $z = 45$.

The second row is $-y + 4z = 150$. Substituting $z = 45$ gives us $-y + 180 = 150$, or $y = 30$.

The third row is $3x + 2y + z = 300$. Substituting $z=45$ and $y=30$ gives us $3x + 60 + 45 = 300$, or $x = 65$.

So the answer is 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
65 \\
30 \\
45 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

You can answer it using matrix algebra in EXCEL.

Below you will find the setup.

[image]